# KNEX order of schmas migrated

Tags: knex.js

How can I find out or influence in which order the schemas in my DB are migrated. From the current order I cannot find out what logic is been used (it's neither alphabetically nor by creation date).

Thanks for any hint!
Jens

```
POD001_backend@0.0.1 migrate /app/backend > babel-node migrate.js
Migrating romantic_bohr... 
Using environment: stage 
Batch 37 
run: 2 migrations 
--> Successfully migrated! 
Migrating boring_lovelace...
```

Answer (score 1):

In every batch the migration order is alphabetical. Since knex adds the timestamp on the beginning, this should also correspond to the creation time of the migration. However which migrations get into each batch depends on the way you handle your project. It can happen that a migration created very early will be merged to the project much later than an older much simpler migration. If you meanwhile migrate your database, the newer one is executed and the older one still waits for revisions...

Answer (score 0):

The order is alphabetical (Array.sort())

https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/master/src/migrate/index.js#L132

Comment: Hi Mikael, thanks for your help! I am not too sure whether you got my question correctly (or whether I got your answer :-). When I run a DB migration one DB schema after another gets migrated. My question is in what order the schemas are migrated. The are defenitely not in alphabetical order for me.

Comment: @JensGössing I don't think that I understood your question nor clarification :) When you run migration for one schema after another the migrations are ran in the order that you have defined them to be ran in your code. I think you need to add some example about what are you doing.

Comment: sorry for late response. let me present an extract of the logs of my latest knex migration to you:
> POD001_backend@0.0.1 migrate /app/backend
> babel-node migrate.js
Migrating romantic_bohr...
Using environment: stage
Batch 37 run: 2 migrations
--> Successfully migrated!
Migrating boring_lovelace...
[]

As you can see the first two schemas migrated are romantic_bohr and boring_lovelace. This is not alphabetic order as the first schema in my app then would be "admiring_clarck".

So my question is: How can I adjust the order in which a migration is currently executed!?

Comment: @JensGössing please use edit button of the question. These comments cannot be formatted sanely.

Comment: @JensGössing your knex config and mirgration directory listing of your project would be needed too.